# Using "::" instead of "module ..." for Ruby namespacing

Tags: ruby, namespaces

In Ruby, is there a difference between writing `class Foo::Bar` and `module Foo; class Bar` for namespacing? If so, what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `class Foo::Bar`, but the `Foo` module hasn't been defined yet, an exception will be raised, whereas the `module Foo; class Bar` method will define `Foo` if it hasn't been defined yet.

Also, with the block format, you could define multiple classes within:

```
module Foo
  class Bar; end
  class Baz; end
end
```

Comment: Also if `Foo` was defined as a class `Foo::Bar` won't raise the exception while `module Foo; end` will raise a `TypeError` since `Foo` is not a module but a class.

Answer (score 7):

Also notice this curious bit of Ruby-ismness:

```
FOO = 123

module Foo
  FOO = 555
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
      puts FOO
    end
  end
end

class Foo::Bar
  def glorf
    puts FOO
  end
end

puts Foo::Bar.new.baz    # -> 555
puts Foo::Bar.new.glorf  # -> 123
```

Comment: can you provide some explanation behind why this is happening in your example? I would think that the second call would also return 555.

Comment: @WillsonMock Good question. I would almost open up a new SO question for this. I found the answer back when I wrote this, but now I don't remember it any more and can't find it again. Should have posted it in the answer here too :-/ Happens with classes too btw. not just modules.

Comment: cool, in case you want to follow, this is the new SO question I've posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119724/ruby-lexical-scope-vs-inheritance