# Ruby Constants and Namespacing

Tags: ruby, namespaces, constants

Is there a difference between the following 2 snippets of code?

```
# 1st snippet
class A
  class B
    # some code here
  end
end

# 2nd snippet
class A::B
  # some code here
end
```

If there is a difference, can you help me understand what the difference is and why you would use one version versus the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be mostly syntactic sugar for organizing your code - whichever way makes sense to you is the "correct" way.  The only exception is that with the 2nd snippet, if `class A` hasn't already been defined you'll get an error.  For the most part this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927566/using-instead-of-module-for-ruby-namespacing), though since you are nesting classes in classes instead of classes in a module, I'll go ahead and link the [Module docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html), which explains the difference between modules and classes in Ruby and may help you interpret that SO answer in the context of your own question.