# Ruby - Lexical scope vs Inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, lexical-scope

This is a continuation this original SO question: [Using "::" instead of "module ..." for Ruby namespacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927566/using-instead-of-module-for-ruby-namespacing/6928843#comment21276092_6928843)

In the original SO question, here is the scenario presented which I'm still having trouble understanding:

```
FOO = 123

module Foo
  FOO = 555
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
      puts FOO
    end
  end
end

class Foo::Bar
  def glorf
    puts FOO
  end
end

puts Foo::Bar.new.baz    # -> 555
puts Foo::Bar.new.glorf  # -> 123
```

Can someone provide some explanation behind why the first call is returning 555 and why the second call is returning 123?

Comment: Willson, which answer below do you think is worthy of the bounty? Thanks

Comment: Hint: add "puts Module.nesting" after the two puts in your code.
See also this: http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/constant-name-resolution-in-ruby/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can think of each appearance of `module Something`, `class Something` or `def something` as a “gateway” into a new scope. When Ruby is searching for the definition of a name that has been referenced it first looks in the current scope (the method, class or module), and if it isn’t found there it will go back through each containing “gateway” and search the scope there.

In your example the method `baz` is defined as

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
      puts FOO
    end
  end
end
```

So when trying to determine the value of `FOO`, first the class `Bar` is checked, and since `Bar` doesn’t contain a `FOO` the search moves up through the “`class Bar` gateway” into the `Foo` module which is the containing scope. `Foo` does contain a constant `FOO` (555) so this is the result you see.

The method `glorf` is defined as:

```
class Foo::Bar
  def glorf
    puts FOO
  end
end
```

Here the “gateway” is `class Foo::Bar`, so when `FOO` isn’t found inside `Bar` the “gateway” passes through the `Foo` module and straight into the top level, where there is another `FOO` (123) which is what is displayed.

Note how using `class Foo::Bar` creates a single “gateway”, skipping over the scope of `Foo`, but `module Foo; class Bar ...` opens two separate “gateways”

Comment: Btw. the gateway term. In the Ruby sources there seems to be what one could call a "scope stack". So each time you type `class` or `module` a new scope is pushed onto this stack. When Ruby then searches for variables or constants it consults this stack from bottom to top, ending in the top-level `main` if it didn't find the variable on the way up. In the case of `class Foo::Bar` it really should push TWO scopes onto the stack (both `Foo` and `Bar`), but it only pushes one, hence we get the "problem".

Comment: How does this differ from the original answer?

Comment: @Casper that makes sense. I read about the “gateway” idea somewhere (can’t remember where unfortunately) as a way of thinking about what’s going on but I haven’t looked at the implementation. I guess one explanation for this behaviour is it allows you to open up a nested class (to monkey patch it) without needing to worry about the enclosing scope interfering.

Answer (score 6):

wow, great question. The best answer I can come up with is in this case you're using the module to define a namespace.

Check this out:

```
FOO = 123

module Foo
  FOO = 555
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
      puts FOO
    end

    def glorf3
      puts ::FOO
    end
  end
end

class Foo::Bar
  def glorf2
    puts Foo::FOO
  end

  def glorf
    puts FOO
  end
end

puts Foo::Bar.new.baz    # -> 555
puts Foo::Bar.new.glorf  # -> 123
puts Foo::Bar.new.glorf2  # -> 555
puts Foo::Bar.new.glorf3  # -> 123
```

So my thought is that when you define:

```
module Foo
  FOO = 555
end
```

you are creating `FOO` in the namespace of `Foo`. So when you use it here:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
      puts FOO
    end
  end
end
```

you are in the `Foo` namespace. However, when you refer to it in:

```
class Foo::Bar
  def glorf
    puts FOO
  end
end
```

`FOO` is coming from the default namespace (as illustrated by `::FOO`).

Comment: thanks for the examples! this makes sense except for one point: when you define the class Foo::Bar, aren't you namespacing it to Foo? Doesn't the "Foo::" part of "Foo::Bar" imply that you're namespacing that class?

Comment: Foo::Bar.new.glorf returning 123 is difficult for me to understand when Foo::Bar.new.baz returns 555.

Comment: I would have thought that too, but it looks like, what's happening is you're namespacing Bar (under Foo) explicitly by Foo::Bar and everything else in that context is still coming from the default namespace.

Comment: Interesting, so it seems like when you're explicitly namespacing the class, the constants will resolve to the default namespace unless you specify otherwise (i.e. Foo::FOO in glorf2) and when you're implicitly namespacing the class, the constants will resolve to namespace unless you specify otherwise (i.e. ::FOO in glorf3).

Comment: Right, that's what I think. Hopefully someone else will comment. This is really interesting...

Answer (score 0):

the first call:

```
puts Foo::Bar.new.baz    # -> 555
```

prints the result of invoking method **baz** of an instance of class **Foo::Bar**

notice that **Foo::Bar#baz** definition **is actually a closure on FOO**. Following ruby's scope rules:

1. **FOO** is searched for in **Foo::Bar** (the class, not the instance) scope, it is not found,
2. **FOO** is searched for in the enclosing scope **Foo** (because we are within the module definition) and it is found there (555)

the second call:

```
puts Foo::Bar.new.glorf  # -> 123
```

prints the result of invoking method **glorf** of an instance of class **Foo::Bar**

notice that **Foo::Bar#glorf** definition this time **is also a closure on FOO**, but if we follow ruby's scope rules you'll notice that the value closed upon this time is **::FOO** (top level scope FOO) in the following way:

1. **FOO** is searched for in **Foo::Bar** (the class, not the instance) namespace, it is not found
2. **FOO** is searched in the enclosing scope ('top level') and it is found there (123)

Answer (score 0):

glorf is a method of class Foo, in `=> [Foo, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

within that scope (i.e. in default/main module), FOO is assigned 123

module Foo is defined as

```
module Foo
  FOO = 555
  class Bar
    def baz
      puts FOO
    end
  end
end
```

where method baz belongs to class Bar in module Foo `=> [Bar, Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

and in that scope FOO was assigned 555

Comment: the 'main' mentioned above is an artifact of irb, actually `FOO=123` is a top-level method that goes into Object class.