# Do you know an alternative ctags generator for Ruby

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags

Exumerant Ctags does not work well with Ruby, you can see there are many hacks in the ruby.c code and basically it fails recognizing many cases. One of the most important is this bit:

```
class SomeModule::SomeClass
end
```

Ctags generates:

```
SomeModule  someclass.rb  /^class SomeModule::SomeClass$/;"  c
```

which is wrong. The correct and expected entry is:

```
SomeClass  someclass.rb  /^class SomeModule::SomeClass$/;"  c
```

This is very limiting. There are some patches for ctags available which does not work, e.g. https://github.com/xtao/overlay/blob/master/dev-util/ctags/files/ctags-5.5.4-ruby-classes.patch but looking on the ctags ruby codebase, this really needs complete rewrite.

So I have been playing with other option which is https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc-tags which works nicer, but it is slow. I mean really SLOW. Generating tags on my project is 2 seconds with ctags but *one hour* with this tool. Really.

I found one old project that was parsing Ruby on it's own and generating tags, but it was only for Ruby 1.8. It was slower than ctags, but not that bad.

So I am searching for some alternatives. Do you know about any other working ruby ctags generators which give you *proper* output and are fast?

Thanks!

**Edit**: I have found very nice project that **works** with Ruby 1.9+ and is accurate and fast. I recommend it:

https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags

Comment: Or maybe if you know fast and working Ruby parser|lexer that is easy to use so I can write my own tags generator. Should work with Ruby 1.8-2.0.

Comment: Side note about using `class SomeModule::SomeClass` : it does not create a lexcical scope with `SomeModule` as parent, you should avoid it -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119724/ruby-lexical-scope-vs-inheritance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Exuberant ctags out of the box doesn’t do a number of useful things:

- It doesn’t deal with:

  ```
  module A::B
  ```
- It doesn’t tag (at least some of) the “operator” methods like `‘==’`
- It doesn’t support qualified tags, `—type=+`
- It doesn’t output tags for constants or attributes.

Patch available, but it is only for version 5.5 and does not work anymore.

Other projects:

- https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags (best option for Ruby 1.9+)
- https://rubygems.org/gems/rdoc-tags (very slow but works with 1.8)

[Source](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/ImprovingRubyTagsSupport)

Comment: Yeah, I saw this, but I am unable to find this particular patch. I only have the one for 5.5 version which does not work at all.

Comment: I have got rdoc-tags. I have added the link. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already tried that and its slow as hell. E.g. parsing "puppet" project = 1 hour. :-(

Answer (score 19):

Ripper-tags effort does solve everything described here. It is based on official Ruby parser which is also quite fast. https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags

```
gem install ripper-tags
cd your_project/
ripper-tags -R
```

It does also support Emacs as well.

Comment: Ok waiting for more recommendations, but I am pretty happy with ripper-tags. I will accept my own answer just not to confuse readers. :-D

Comment: ripper-tags too doesn't index nested modules: https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags/issues/48

Comment: Yay! Recently ripper-tags added support for nested / constants https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags/pull/44

Answer (score 4):

Add following to your ~/.ctags

```
--regex-ruby=/(^|;)[ \t]*(class|module)[ \t]+([A-Z][[:alnum:]_]+(::[A-Z][[:alnum:]_]+)+)/\3/c,class,constant/
```

So you can:

- deal with: `module A::B`

See more here: https://github.com/bltavares/dot-files/blob/master/ctags

Comment: did you write that regex yourself ?

Comment: No, I copy from the link.

Comment: Didn't work for me and I've regenerated the tag file with `--regex-ruby=/(^|;)[ \t]*(class|module)[ \t]+([A-Z][[:alnum:]_]+(::[A-Z][[:alnum:]_]+)+)/\3/c,class,constant/` included on ~/.ctags

Answer (score 1):

A patch is available as of 2013-02

- https://github.com/fishman/ctags (ctags patch for Ruby, including `rspec`)

the rspec tag generator will not properly recognize `describe` blocks that start with semicolor (`:some-method`), but other than that, it's great.

Comment: Universal ctags didn't work either:

`ctags --version`
Universal Ctags 6.0.0, Copyright (C) 2015-2022 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Mar 26 2023, 05:37:43
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Output version: 0.0
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +gnulib_fnmatch, +gnulib_regex, +iconv, +option-directory, +xpath, +json, +interactive, +yaml, +case-insensitive-filenames, +packcc, +optscript

Comment: I tend to use `ripper-tags` now

Answer (score 1):

There is also https://github.com/eapache/starscope

It doesn't support the extended tag format (yet) but it does other things such as exporting cscope databases.